# Generating a SQL (summary) table from multiple other tables

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a unit which is comprised of several subparts. I have one table for each sub-part which looks something like this:

```
Part#ID    PartBarcode   BuildDate   comments
------    -----------   ---------   --------
##        someBC        datetime    string
##        someBC        datetime    string
##        someBC        datetime    string
....
```

I have 3 of the above tables

Then I have one subpart table which looks like this:

```
PartID    PartSubBarcode1   PartSubBarcode1    PartSubBarcode1   BuildDate   comments
          (project code)    (intraproject S/N) (Antenna presence)
------    ---------------   ---------------    ---------------   ---------   --------
##        ABC               123                Z                 Datetime    string
##        ABC               124                X                 Datetime    string
##        ABC               125                Z                 Datetime    string
```

Edit:Each of the barcode subparts represent physical/project attributes.

When then they are all assembled and I have a table with the subparts as a unit

```
AssembledUnitID   Part1ID   Part2ID   Part3ID   Part4ID   ActiveState
---------------   -------   -------   -------   -------   -----------
##                ##        ##        ##        ##        true
##                ##        ##        ##        ##        false
##                ##        ##        ##        ##        true
...
```

I want to create a table which will have the barcodes of all the subparts in the *active* assembled units. The extra catch is, because I have that 1 subpart with the barcode actually broken apart into multiple columns I need some way of concatenating the components into one string for the user to see (or not really...not too big a deal).

```
Part1BC   Part1BuildDate Part2BC Part2BuildDate  ...
-------   -------------- ------- --------------
```

The end game here is to populate a datagridview object on a WinForm in C#.NET for the user to navigate and see the status of an inventory. <strike>It would be nice for this to be one SQL statement filling this table.</strike> The conciseness of the code is not actually important, so long as the end result is the same.

My novice SQL skills in combination with reading forum posts and helps docs is really making my head spin. I have been trying different SELECT statements but none of them seem to really be getting my anywhere.

Additional information:
I'm making a winform with a datagrid view in C#.NET
I'm connecting to an Access 2007 .mdb Database. I'm storing my queries in my C# solution in the .xsd file. 
Any more info needed?

---

**EDIT:**
Did it! Here's what I did to solve this! 
In the C# .xsd designer I made a new DataTable. Through the datatable's table adapter I created a query with text like this:

```
SELECT 
            UnitBarcodes.GroupID + UnitBarcodes.Version
                + UnitBarcodes.SubSerial + UnitBarcodes.AntennaStatus AS [Unit Barcode],
            Subpart1.Barcode AS [part1 Board Barcode],
            Subpart2.Barcode AS [part2 Board Barcode],
            Subpart3.Barcode AS [part3 Board Barcode],
            AssembledUnits.DateAssembled AS [Date Assembled],
            Subpart1.OnBoardBuildDate AS [Firmware Build Date] FROM  ((((MainBoards INNER JOIN
            AssembledUnits ON Subpart1.ID = AssembledUnits.Subpart1ID)
    INNER JOIN
            UnitBarcodes ON AssembledUnits.UnitBarcodesID = UnitBarcodes.ID)
    INNER JOIN
            Subpart2 ON AssembledUnits.Subpart2ID = Subpart2.ID) 
    INNER JOIN
            Subpart3 ON AssembledUnits.Subpart3ID = Subpart3.ID)
    WHERE     (AssembledUnits.ActiveState = ?) AND (AssembledUnits.DateAssembled > ?)
```

Once I fill the dataTable I set

```
bindingSource1.DataSource=
dataGridView2.AutoResizeColumns();
```

(before I call the query I also set 'dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = true;' and of course created the dataGridView2 object on my form)

and voila! It works! What a learning experience (and way simpler than I first thought)

Comment: You should definitely read about normalization. Having many tables for the same data (parts) like you say: `I have 3 of the above tables` is a no-no. Having many columns for the same data (PartSubBarcode_XX and Part_XX_ID) is another no-no. Try to normalize or post the normalization problem as a new question at SO. An intoduction to normalization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Each of the parts are produced independently, and have different build dates and may, in the future (as parts fail), be assembled into different whole units. In the example each subpart table has the same columns but in reality they only share a few columns/characteristics. Some have more/less/different.

Comment: As for the barcode in the one subpart being split apart it seemed like the thing to do because the barcode itself has 4 components representing different things.Of the four components, 3 describe physical characteristics of the part and the fourth is a unique number for a project (but maybe not universally unique). I figured by breaking it all apart like this I *was* reducing redundancy. But you think not?

Comment: Regardless, I will read the linked article and see what I can do.

Comment: If with `(PartSubBarcode1, PartSubBarcode2, PartSubBarcode3)` you mean `(ColourCode, StrengthCode, DiameterCode)`, then it is OK (and actually a normalizing step). But we can't know that until you describe it with more details.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't do it in one query**

This is a moderately complex problem which you're making even more difficult by not wanting to write code. Also MS Access has more limitations than a SQL Server database in terms of writing queries, so you're likely to find it even more difficult.

Comment: I figured someone smarter than me knew how to do this in one statement. But if that's not ideal, how might you suggest approaching this in multiple steps?

Comment: You're going to have to clean up your explanation a little, maybe use an example with only a couple rows to illustrate what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your PartIDs are unique across all tables, you could try using a view:

first declare your view as follows:

(note that I have included table named in [brackets] for your renaming convenience)

```
CREATE VIEW View_AllSubparts AS

SELECT PartID, PartBarcode AS 'Barcode', BuildDate FROM [SubpartTable1]
UNION
SELECT PartID, PartBarcode AS 'Barcode', BuildDate FROM [SubpartTable2]
UNION
SELECT PartID, PartBarcode AS 'Barcode', BuildDate FROM [SubpartTable3]
UNION
SELECT PartID, PartSubBarcode1 + PartSubBarcode2 + PartSubBarcode3 AS 'Barcode', BuildDate FROM [SpecialSubpartTable]
GO
```

From then on you can refer to this view in statements as you would a table.

From there, you can build your select for your units by joining on this view multiple times

```
SELECT Part1.Barcode, Part1.BuildDate , Part2.Barcode, Part2.BuildDate , Part3.Barcode, Part3.BuildDate , Part4.Barcode, Part4.BuildDate 
FROM [AssembledUnit]
JOIN View_AllSubparts Part1 ON AssembledUnit.Part1ID = Part1.PartID
JOIN View_AllSubparts Part2 ON AssembledUnit.Part2ID = Part2.PartID
JOIN View_AllSubparts Part3 ON AssembledUnit.Part3ID = Part3.PartID
JOIN View_AllSubparts Part4 ON AssembledUnit.Part4ID = Part4.PartID
```

Note that I do not use Access 2007 regularly, but I did a quick check and I think there's nothing here that Access will refuse. Let me know.

Comment: I tried this but Access doesn't like creating VIEWs via the query designer, seems like there's another way but I have not found it yet. Besides I think this lead me in the right enough direction to do what I want. Will update when confirmed.